# POST verb not allowed

Tags: html

A bit basic, but I have tried some of the methods to tackle the following error but could not get the right solution.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form  method="post">
            <input type="text" name="query1"></input>
            <input type="text" name="query2"></input>
            <input type="submit"></input>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Error on running : 
HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.

In the mappings of IIS, I have added the POST method but that did not work! 
Suggestions please!

Answer (score 3):

The following code has solved the problem for me(it's for php on iis).

> **web.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script">
            <remove name="PHP55_via_FastCGI" />
            <add name="PHP55_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
            <add name="HTML_via_FastCGI" path="*.html" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
            <add name="HTM_via_FastCGI" path="*.htm" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.5\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <fileExtensions>
                    <add fileExtension=".php" allowed="true" />
                </fileExtensions>
                <verbs>
                    <add verb="POST"   allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="GET"    allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="HEAD"   allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="DELETE" allowed="true" />
                    <add verb="PUT"    allowed="true" />
                </verbs>
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more, this could be a variety of problems. With that in mind, here is a list of possible fixes for your issue:

### Cause 1

> This problem occurs because the client makes an HTTP request by using
> an HTTP method that does not comply with the HTTP specifications.
>
> To resolve this problem, see resolution 1.

### Cause 2

> This problem occurs because a client makes an HTTP request by sending
> the POST method to a page that is configured to be handled by the
> StaticFile handler. For example, a client sends the POST method to a
> static HTML page. However, pages that are configured for the
> StaticFile handler do not support the POST method.
>
> To resolve this problem, see resolution 2.

### Resolution 1

> Make sure that the client sends a request that contains a valid HTTP
> method. To do this, follow these steps:
>
> 1. Click Start, type Notepad in
>    the Start Search box, right-click Notepad, and then click Run as
>    administrator.
> 2. Note If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a
>    confirmation, type the password, or provide confirmation. On the File
>    menu, click Open. In the File name box, type
>    %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config, and then
>    click Open.
> 3. In the ApplicationHost.config file, locate the 
>    tag.
> 4. Make sure that all the handlers use valid HTTP methods.
> 5. Save the ApplicationHost.config file.

### Resolution 2

> Send the POST request to a page that is configured to be handled by a
> handler other than the StaticFile handler (for example, the ASPClassic
> handler). Or, change the request that is being handled by the
> StaticFile handler so that it is a GET request instead of a POST
> request.

***[MSDN Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942051)***

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have 2 errors:
1) If your file extension is *.html change it to for example ***.asp, *.php** and it will work.
2)The `input` tag doesn't have closing tag.